Identify a specific string in a column and count number of unique letters by group in R
I have a dataframe df1
df1<- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 37)), c("material","condition", "pID")) df1$material <- c("FBZOIKS","FBZOIKS","FBZOIKS","FBZOIKS","VNTYALQ","VNTYALQ","VNTYALQ","HMRCJXU","HMRCJXU","HMRCJXU","HMRCJXU","HMRCJXU","CURHJXM","UXJMRCH","UXJMRCH","XMRCUJH","XMRCUJH","XMRCUJH","FBZOIKS","FBZOIKS", "FBZOIKS","FBZOIKS","VNTYALQ","VNTYALQ","VNTYALQ","VNTYALQ","HMRCJXU","HMRCJXU","HMRCJXU","HMRCJXU","CURHJXM","CURHJXM","UXJMRCH","UXJMRCH","XMRCUJH","XMRCUJH","XMRCUJH") df1$condition <- c("false"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","","false"," "," "," "," ",""," false"," ", " "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," false"," "," "," "," "," ","") df1$pID <- c("p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1"," p1","p1"," p2"," p2", " p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2"," p2","p2")
and I need to create two columns grouping them by pID: block and Nletters_block.
For block, I need to identify the first 'false' in the column condition and give a value of 1 until the next 'false' for that pID is identified. When the next is identified, I need to assign a value of 2. If a next is identified I need to assign a value of 3 and so on.
For Nletters_block, I need to calculate for each participant and block, the unique number of letters that are embedded in the column material.
If I could use the dplyr library, I would be even better.
Below is what I would like to obtain:
material  condition pID  block  Nletters_block
FBZOIKS   false     p1   1      21
FBZOIKS             p1   1      21
FBZOIKS             p1   1      21
FBZOIKS             p1   1      21
VNTYALQ             p1   1      21
VNTYALQ             p1   1      21
VNTYALQ             p1   1      21
HMRCJXU             p1   1      21
HMRCJXU             p1   1      21
HMRCJXU             p1   1      21
HMRCJXU             p1   1      21
HMRCJXU             p1   1      21
CURHJXM   false     p1   2      7
UXJMRCH             p1   2      7
UXJMRCH             p1   2      7
XMRCUJH             p1   2      7
XMRCUJH             p1   2      7
XMRCUJH             p1   2      7
FBZOIKS   false     p2   1      21
FBZOIKS             p2   1      21
FBZOIKS             p2   1      21
FBZOIKS             p2   1      21
VNTYALQ             p2   1      21
VNTYALQ             p2   1      21
VNTYALQ             p2   1      21
VNTYALQ             p2   1      21
HMRCJXU             p2   1      21
HMRCJXU             p2   1      21
HMRCJXU             p2   1      21
HMRCJXU             p2   1      21
CURHJXM   false     p2   2      7
CURHJXM             p2   2      7
UXJMRCH             p2   2      7
UXJMRCH             p2   2      7
XMRCUJH             p2   2      7
XMRCUJH             p2   2      7
XMRCUJH             p2   2      7


Your condition and pID columns have inconsistent values, e.g. "false" vs. " false" and "p1" vs. " p1". I presume that was unintended and the two should be treated the same?

Yes, unintended and should be treated the same.

First grouping by pID then by pID and block. Counting the characters by pasting all material and subsequently splitting.
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(block = cumsum(condition == "false"), .by = pID) %>% 
  mutate(Nletters_block = length(unique(unlist(strsplit(
                            paste(material, collapse=""), "")))), 
         .by = c(pID, block))
   material condition pID block Nletters_block
1   FBZOIKS     false  p1     1             21
2   FBZOIKS            p1     1             21
3   FBZOIKS            p1     1             21
4   FBZOIKS            p1     1             21
5   VNTYALQ            p1     1             21
6   VNTYALQ            p1     1             21
7   VNTYALQ            p1     1             21
8   HMRCJXU            p1     1             21
9   HMRCJXU            p1     1             21
10  HMRCJXU            p1     1             21
11  HMRCJXU            p1     1             21
12  HMRCJXU            p1     1             21
13  CURHJXM     false  p1     2              7
14  UXJMRCH            p1     2              7
15  UXJMRCH            p1     2              7
16  XMRCUJH            p1     2              7
17  XMRCUJH            p1     2              7
18  XMRCUJH            p1     2              7
19  FBZOIKS     false  p2     1             21
20  FBZOIKS            p2     1             21
21  FBZOIKS            p2     1             21
22  FBZOIKS            p2     1             21
23  VNTYALQ            p2     1             21
24  VNTYALQ            p2     1             21
25  VNTYALQ            p2     1             21
26  VNTYALQ            p2     1             21
27  HMRCJXU            p2     1             21
28  HMRCJXU            p2     1             21
29  HMRCJXU            p2     1             21
30  HMRCJXU            p2     1             21
31  CURHJXM     false  p2     2              7
32  CURHJXM            p2     2              7
33  UXJMRCH            p2     2              7
34  UXJMRCH            p2     2              7
35  XMRCUJH            p2     2              7
36  XMRCUJH            p2     2              7
37  XMRCUJH            p2     2              7

Data
df1 <- structure(list(material = c("FBZOIKS", "FBZOIKS", "FBZOIKS",
"FBZOIKS", "VNTYALQ", "VNTYALQ", "VNTYALQ", "HMRCJXU", "HMRCJXU",
"HMRCJXU", "HMRCJXU", "HMRCJXU", "CURHJXM", "UXJMRCH", "UXJMRCH",
"XMRCUJH", "XMRCUJH", "XMRCUJH", "FBZOIKS", "FBZOIKS", "FBZOIKS",
"FBZOIKS", "VNTYALQ", "VNTYALQ", "VNTYALQ", "VNTYALQ", "HMRCJXU",
"HMRCJXU", "HMRCJXU", "HMRCJXU", "CURHJXM", "CURHJXM", "UXJMRCH",
"UXJMRCH", "XMRCUJH", "XMRCUJH", "XMRCUJH"), condition = c("false",
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "false", "", "",
"", "", "", "false", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
"", "false", "", "", "", "", "", ""), pID = c("p1", "p1", "p1",
"p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p1",
"p1", "p1", "p1", "p1", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2",
"p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2", "p2",
"p2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -37L))


Thank you for your answer, but it gives me an error: Error in mutate():
! Can't supply .by when .data is a grouped data frame.

Check if your data is already grouped. You may want to do df1 %>% ungroup() %>% ... with your original data.

My favorite thing about the .by syntax introduced with dplyr 1.1.0 in early 2023 was that it means you don't have to use group_by() + ungroup() and keep track of what state of grouping your data frame is in at each step. Instead, you can specify grouping within each step that needs it.

@JonSpring Love it too, almost exclusively use it. Only when I want to introduce a new group variable from within group_by I revert to it.

Thank you @AndreWildberg It works now with ungroup():  df1 %>% ungroup(pID) %>%   mutate(block = cumsum(condition == "false"), .by = pID) %>%    mutate(Nletters_block = length(unique(unlist(strsplit(                             paste(material, collapse=""), "")))),           .by = c(pID, block))
